# Not able to get the items for a particular drive/onedrive

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-teams

I got a drive `id` from a Microsoft Teams generated SharePoint site list using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/group-id/sites/root/lists/list-id/drive
```

I can successfully get the details of the drive by calling:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/drive-id
```

However, I am getting an invalid request error when trying to get the items of the drive

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/drive-id/items

{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "0d83a954-ed79-4a4a-ae28-f963db4b6f2f",
            "date": "2018-03-26T05:10:37"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try [this](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_list_children)? 
graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/{drive-id}/root/children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're URI is a little off. You can only use the `items` path when referencing a specific `DriveItem` (i.e. `/drives/{id}/items/{id}`).

If you're looking for a collection of `DriveItem` resources in a drive, you need to call `/drives/{driveId}/{path}/children`. The `{path}` is the folder you want to retrieve the catalog of `DriveItem` resources from. For the "root" directory you can simply use `root`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/root/children
```

Also, you generally shouldn't use the `beta` version of Microsoft Graph. It can experience breaking changes without warning (and does). It isn't safe for production use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `/root/delta`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/drives/drive id/root/delta
```